# interesting Regular Expression

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Hi very interesting Regex Expression, i tried a lot of time,but some difficulties in it.
Regex rule:

> 1. user can use following characters all small([a-z]), all    capital([A-Z]), numbers([0-9]) and the follownig symbols
>      !~*:;<>+#-£$&_?(){}[] and one space. All characers are  in any order,
>      but restiriction    are following:
> 2. input can not start with digit.
> 3. user can use zero or one white space any where in the input, but input can not start and end with white space.
> 4. input must contains at least one special following character!~*:;<>+#-£$&_?(){}[] in any order.

1. input length is in between 6-15.
   Question: Regular expression which fullfills the above requirment. i have spent many of hours on it.but make the following Regex expression.

> Regex='/^([a-zA-Z]|!|\~|*|\:|\;|\<|>|+|#|-|\£|\$|\&|_|\?|{|}|[|]|(|)){1,20}(\s){0,1}([a-zA-Z]|!|\~|*|\:|\;|\<|>|+|#|-|\d|\£|\$|\&|_|\?|{|}|[|]|(|)){1,20}(!|\~|*|\:|\;|\<|>|+|#|-|\£|\$|\&|_|\?|{|}|[|]|(|)){1,}$/i';
>   it fullfills all rule but not rule no.4.

complete regex which fullfills the above rules will be appreciated.

Comment: "...and now you have two problems." Instead of the hours spent on the regex you could have spent 10 minutes checking each requirement individually. (If it's technically impossible to use anything other than a single regex, it's a different matter, but it rarely is.)

Comment: Do you have any test strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints before getting to the solution.

1. You use the modifier `i`, means "case independent" matching. So no `a-zA-Z` needed just use `a-z` or `A-Z`.
2. From your list of characters `[a-zA-Z]|!|\~|*|\:|\;|\<|>|+|#|-|\£|\$|\&|_|\?|{|}|[|]|(|)`

   1. There are some characters that needs escaping, since they are special in regex.
   2. Skip the alternation and put all characters in the char class (you can also spare the escaping then)
3. To enforce some of your rules you need [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

So your regex (for php) can look like:

```
^(?![\d ])(?![^ ]*[ ][^ ]*[ ])(?=.*[!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?{}\[\]()])[a-z\d!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?{}\[\]() ]{6,15}(?<![ ])$
```

If you need the **regex for JavaScript**, you can not use the lookbehind assertion. You can replace it also by a lookahead:

```
^(?![\d ])(?!.* $)(?![^ ]*[ ][^ ]*[ ])(?=.*[!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?{}\[\]()])[a-z\d!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?{}\[\]() ]{6,15}$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?358rc) (Note. I have used there [^ \r]) just because I need multiline for testing)

### The regex explained:

- `[a-z\d!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?{}\[\]() ]{6,15}` matches all characters you want to allow, in the required length.
- `(?![\d ])` [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that ensures the string does not start with a digit or a space.
- `(?![^ ]*[ ][^ ]*[ ])` [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that ensures the string does not have more than one space
- `(?=.*[!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?{}\[\]()])` [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that ensures the string does have one of your special symbols
- `(?<![ ])$` [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that ensures the string does not end with a space.

### Unicode:

JavaScript does not support this natively!

If you want to support Unicode letters instead of only the old ASCII letters, then replace
`[a-z]` with `\p{L}`. You can then also remove the `i` modifier, since `\p{L}` is a [Unicode property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) that matches all letters in any language (only complete letters, not combined ones, there you could use `[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}]`)

Comment: i test your regex on the following site [http://www.cyber-reality.com/regexy.html] but results are Invalid regular expression. kindly help

Comment: I assumed you use php, didn't notice the JavaScript tag. For which language do you need it? That side is using JavaScript and there the lookbehind assertion is not supported.

Comment: i need a  regex which used in javascript and also in php.

Comment: I updated my answer. The regex for javascript will also work in php.

Comment: thanks sir, your code completely work for me. this is very helpful material for me and other. thanks for your sharing knowledge. i am very happy from your code.

Comment: kindly tell me how to convert string which contain $ sign for example  $name ="$dky01"; when i get this data from input. the data is not in string form. how to escape from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
<?php
    $symbols = '!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?(){}\[\]';
    $regex = "/^(?=.*[$symbols])(?=.{6,15}\$)(?!.*  )[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 $symbols]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$";
?>
```

If any of the following explanations are unclear, please ask, referring to their number:

1. Note that we've factored out the list of symbols for convenience.
2. Note that we've escaped `-`, `[`, and `]`, as these are meaningful characters in character classes. It's possible to *not* escape them as long as the `-` is at the beginning or end, and the `]` is at the beginning, but since we're mixing `$symbols` with other characters, we can't be sure where the "beginning" or "end" really is.
3. `(?=...)` are known as *lookaheads*. They're useful for asserting multiple conditions. For example, the `(?=.*[$symbols])` asserts that there is a symbol *somewhere* (hence the `.*`); and the `(?=.{6,15}\$)` asserts that, from beginning to end, the string is between 6 and 15 characters in length (note that the `$` is escaped only because it exists in a double-quote).
4. The `(?!...)` is known as a *negative lookahead*. The `(?!.*  )` asserts that there are no two consecutive spaces anywhere.
5. The remainder should be obvious.

Comment: i test it on following site [http://www.cyber-reality.com/regexy.html]  and your regex is ^(?=.*[!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?(){}\[\]])(?=.{6,15}\$)(?!.*  )[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?(){}\[\]]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$ but not work. kindly help to understand.

Comment: this code work for me.**^(?![\d ])(?![^ ]*[ ][^ ]*[ ])(?=.*[!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?{}\[\]()])[a-z\d!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?{}\[\]() ]{6,15}(?<![ ])$**      thanks for sharing knowldge.

Comment: This will accept more than one spaces not consecutives. `a b c 1&f` will match.

Comment: @M42 - Ah, I misunderstood his requirement as, "Zero or one spaces, anywhere in the input, _multiple times_." But I see now what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested by @Juhana in the comments, why not test your rules separately rather than make a single over complex regex? something like this. (these are not actual solutions or tested as you didn't provide any test strings, more an example of how to think differently about your problem)

Javascript

```
function verify(string) {
    var length = string.length;

    if (length < 6 || length > 15 || /^\d/.test(string) || /^\s/.test(string) || /\s$/.test(string) || /\s\s/.test(string) || /[!~*:;<>+#-£$&_?(){}[\]]+/.test(string)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

PHP

```
function verify($string) {
    $length = strlen($string);

    if ($length < 6 || $length > 15 || preg_match("/^\d/", $string) || preg_match("/^\s/", $string) || preg_match("/\s$/", $string) || preg_match("/\s\s/", $string) || preg_match("/[!~*:;<>+#-£$&_?(){}[\]]+/", $string)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: his code work for me.**^(?![\d ])(?![^ ]*[ ][^ ]*[ ])(?=.*[!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?{}[]()])[a-z\d!~*:;<>+#\-£$&_?{}[]() ]{6,15}(?<![ ])$** thanks for sharing knowldge.